# Find indices of 5 closest samples in distance matrix

Tags: r, matrix, distance

Users

I have a distance matrix dMat and want to find the 5 nearest samples to the first one. What function can I use in R? I know how to find the closest sample (cf. 3rd line of code), but can't figure out how to get the other 4 samples.

The code:

```
Mat <- replicate(10, rnorm(10))
dMat <- as.matrix(dist(Mat))
which(dMat[,1]==min(dMat[,1]))
```

The 3rd line of code finds the index of the closest sample to the first sample.

Thanks for any help!

Best,
Chega

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `order` to do this:

```
head(order(dMat[-1,1]),5)+1
[1] 10  3  4  8  6
```

Note that I removed the first one, as you presumably don't want to include the fact that your reference point is 0 distance away from itself.

Comment: Thanks for this quick response! Allow me one question: I do understand "order" and "head", but what is the purpose of the last term "+1"?

Answer (score 5):

Alternative using `sort`:

```
sort(dMat[,1], index.return = TRUE)$ix[1:6]
```

It would be nice to add a `set.seed(.)` when using `random numbers` in matrix so that we could show the results are identical. I will skip the results here.

**Edit (correct solution):** The above solution will only work if the first element is *always* the smallest! Here's the correct solution that will always give the 5 closest values to the first element of the column:

```
> sort(abs(dMat[-1,1] - dMat[1,1]), index.return=TRUE)$ix[1:5] + 1
```

Example:

```
> dMat <- matrix(c(70,4,2,1,6,80,90,100,3), ncol=1)
# James' solution
> head(order(dMat[-1,1]),5) + 1
[1] 4 3 9 2 5 # values are 1,2,3,4,6 (wrong)
# old sort solution
> sort(dMat[,1], index.return = TRUE)$ix[1:6]
[1] 4 3 9 2 5 1 #  values are 1,2,3,4,6,70 (wrong)
# Correct solution
> sort(abs(dMat[-1,1] - dMat[1,1]), index.return=TRUE)$ix[1:5] + 1
[1] 6 7 8 5 2 # values are 80,90,100,6,4 (right)
```

Comment: Thanks - also for the hint with set.seed() - makes absolutely sense!

Comment: Another alternative for the general case is to return the n+1 closest indices and remove the first, ie `head(order(dMat[,1]),6)[-1]`

Comment: @Arun Ah yes, this would only work if for column n you want to refer to element n. But this is what the distance matrix would return.